# Azure Data Factory Copy Activity Copying Date Fields with trailin 0's

Tags: azure-data-factory

Whenever copying a table with ADF from Azure SQLDB where a field is Date type e.g. 16/06/2023 the copy activity will add the following additional 0's to the date e.g. 16/06/2023 00:00:00.

I think the copy activity is attempting to add a timestamp, although the Date type on SQLDB is just 'Date' type.

So, can someone take a look at copy activity and let me know how to prevent the 00:00:00 from being added to the Date field?
[image]

The sink is as follows:

[image]

The desTable parameters are as follows:

[image]

And the connection is as follows:

[image]

From the above copy activity, I can't see why it's adding the timestamp or 00:00:00 to the end of the Date fields

Comment: Give the DateTime format as `yyyy-MM-dd` in the **Mapping** tab of copy activity.

Comment: You can the use the format datetime option for date. **@formatdatetime(utcnow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the 00:00:00 from being added to the Date field, you can give the DateTime format as `yyyy-MM-dd` in the **Mapping** tab of copy activity.

[image]

Once you have given the `dateTime` format, you can run the pipeline again and it should not include the time component in the destination column.